# mongodb exculde matched to the data?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, nosql

there are some data in mongodb:

```
{'name': 'bob', age: 12}
{'name': 'sam': age: 34}
{'name': 'byaelle': age: 22}
```

if I want to get the data of name include `am`
I can use

```
{'name': {'$regex': 'am'}}
```

But, how can I get the  data of name exclude `am`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can just reverse with [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$not": /am/  } })
```

But since it's a [`$regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) you can just do this:

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": /^((?!am).)*$/ })
```

Or

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$regex": "^((?!am).)*$", "$options": "gm" } })
```

Making sure that the content matches over multiple lines if your string is formed that way.

---

For multiple fragments to exclude you can separate them in the expression using `|`. For example to exclude words containing "bo" or "am":

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$regex": "^((?!bo|am).)*$", "$options": "gm" } })
```

Or use the [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator ( "not" `$in` ) which accepts regular expressions:

```js
db.collection.find({ "name": { "$nin": [/bo/,/am/] } })
```

Comment: if I want get name exclude `am` and `bo` and so on?

Comment: @nataila `^((?!bo|am).)*$` so use `|`. which sort of means "or". Get the idea?

Comment: if I want use `$not`?

Comment: @nataila Explained above. In the future, you only get to ask **one** question per question submitted here. You should be posting additional questions if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/#op._S_not) operator with a **regular expression objects** because `$not` cannot have a `$regex`

```js
db.collection.find( { "name": { "$not" : /am/ }})
```

You can also use the following  regex [`^((?!am).)*$`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/3100115) to match text that doesn't contain a word.

```
collection.find({ 'name': { '$regex': '^((?!am).)*$' }})
```